# Debugging .NET Core on WSL by launching directly from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Everything I've read about debugging C# programs on Windows Subsystem for Linux either uses Visual Studio Code, or tells you to launch the program through bash then attach the debugger to the process.

This method works, but it's slow to initiate every time I'd like to debug a change. Is there a way to setup Visual Studio to start remote debugging from the IDE similar to how it's done in C++?

Comment: You mean C# in Linux?

Comment: Yes, although in this case, specifically Windows Subsystem for Linux running on Windows 10.

Comment: May be it's not possible with Visual Studio. You've to use VS Code. See [this tutorial](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started-with-dotnet-tutorial?initial-os=linux). Also Visual Studio hasn't any Linux C# package.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug the .Net Core application on WSL2 from Visual Studio 2019 now.

You need to install/update to version Visual Studio 2019 v16.9.1.

There are the [Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-dotnet-core-in-wsl-2?view=vs-2019#prerequisites), You can refer to [Start debugging with WSL 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-dotnet-core-in-wsl-2?view=vs-2019#start-debugging-with-wsl-2).